# How do you say: "I was doing many things at the same time"

Tags: phrase-request, politeness, register

I work with people that speaks in English (my native language is Spanish).
Yesterday I gave the wrong information to a coworker, so I wanted to apologize and explain that my mind was doing several tasks at the time and that's why I sent him the wrong information, but I'm not sure how to say it properly.
Could you tell me the best way to say this?

I tried this: "I'm sorry, my head was at several tasks at the time. But here is the correct info..."

Comment: That would be called [*multitasking*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/multitasking)

Comment: A caveat: *I was multitasking* is **cant**; that phrase is fashionable at the moment, and is often used jocularly, and as a result, the person to whom you are apologizing could feel that you think your error was fairly insignificant.   Harukogirl's language is neutral, and does not pose that risk.

Comment: [I work with people who speak Spanish. People is plural in English.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for idioms or stock phrases, you might say that you have [too many irons in the fire](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/irons-in-the-fire--too-many), or that you're [juggling too many things at once](https://www.google.com/search?q=juggling%20too%20many%20things).

Answer (score 3):

I would say something like "I'm sorry, I was working on several things at once and sent you the wrong information. Here is the correct information."